# android ubuntu installation problem

Tags: installation, ubuntu-10.04, android-virtual-device, android-sdk-2.3

I am trying to install android SDK on ubuntu.

 I am following the steps [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html).

 However, when I type in android in the terminal, I am getting the error

```
android: command not found
```

What is the solution? Why is this happening?

 I searched on internet and found a solution that I should change etc/apt/sources.list

 But it did not work. 
Thank you.

Comment: This belongs at www.askubuntu.com

Comment: @Jk I do not think this is a ubuntu specific problem. One might get the same problem installing on windows too.

Comment: Then it belongs on superuser. Not here.

Comment: @bmargulies How do I migrate it to superuser?

Comment: The solution is going to be linux specific (ish) though.

Comment: @IslandCow I'd like to move it then to superuser. Can you help me do that?

Comment: Some people have to vote to migrate it. You could click on flag for moderator attention and ask a diamond to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the android binaries to your PATH.

http://www.troubleshooters.com/linux/prepostpath.htm